# GIT merge develop into feature branch -- after the same branch was merged and reverted

Tags: git, merge, workflow, rebase

I am in a pretty sticky situation with a merge, I hope someone can help me.

A feature branch was merged into develop some time ago, all good.
Because that feature was not required for a release, the merge was reverted.
In the meantime some more feature branches were merged into develop.

Now, it is time to re-merge the same feature branch into develop.
As expected, when I try to do that, git will notice that my changes were deleted, so it automatically deletes those files/changes that were part of the original merge in my local feature branch.

Is there a way to fix this: merge/rebase develop into my feature branch, but keeping all my changes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was easier than I thought:

- updated local develop with git pull
- found the ref of the revert commit with git log, copied
- reverted that with git revert <ref_here>, my local develop is pre-revert now
- git checkout to my feature branch, and finally git merge develop.